# use the EntityType with text input

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I have created an `EntityType` form where you can add to your participation to an event the  field and your position. Unfortunately the number and name of the fields is updated dynamically on the page so when creating the form, I don't have all the fields available (or worse some that doesn't exist anymore)

For simplicity I would like to use a simple textType, where my javascripts could enter an `Id` number and link the corresponding element from the db.

the code is very simple

```php
class FieldPositionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('position', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Position::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            ])
            ->add('field', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Field::class,
                'choice_label' => 'id'
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Participation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

but instead of `EntityType`, I would prefer `TextType`.

I imagine that I need to perform some modification on my setter but I have no clue how to transform an Id into a Entity as the `EntityType` does.

Comment: [Data Transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) might help.

Comment: Entity field will show you all entries of that class, if you do not want all of them use query_builder option. And everything would work then out of the box as it does. Not good to mix old fashioned way with pure oop approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad), the [dataTransformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#creating-the-transformer) was the solution.

So just for the `position`, I created a **dataTransformer**

```php
class PositionToIdTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function transform($position)
    {
        if (null === $position) {
            return '';
        }

        return $position->getId();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($id)
    {
        if (!$id){
            return;
        } 

        $position = $this->em->getRepository(Position::class)->find($id);

        if (null === $position){
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf("the position '%s' does not exist!", $id));
        }

        return $position;

    }
}
```

that I use in my `formBuilder`:

```php
class FieldPositionType extends AbstractType
{
    private $pt; //PositionToIdTransformer

    public function __construct(PositionToIdTransformer $pt)
    {
        $this->pt = $pt;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('position', TextType::class)
        ;

        $builder->get('position')->addModelTransformer($this->pt);
    }
}
```

and it work like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

Link for query builder: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

As told in comment try using it. I can not halp you further because I do not see rest of your logic but to limit entries which are shown in entity field it looks like this:

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => User::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'username',
]);
```